# Parse/Swift fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

If anyone has any experience working with Parse using Swift, specifically subclassing PFObject..... I cannot figure out why the saveinbackground call below is throwing the above error?

Thanks!

```
func saveNewPerson(name: String) {

        var myPeeps = [Person]()

        if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {

            if currentUser.valueForKey("myPeeps")?.count < 1 {
                myPeeps = []
            } else {
                myPeeps = currentUser.valueForKey("myPeeps") as! [Person]
            }

            let newPerson = Person(name: name, stores: [:])

        myPeeps.append(newPerson)

        currentUser.setObject(myPeeps, forKey: "myPeeps")

        println(currentUser.valueForKey("myPeeps")?.count)


                //WHY DOES THIS SAVE THROW ERROR FOR NOT INITIALZING?
        currentUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{ succeeded, error in
            if succeeded {
                //3
                println("Saved")
            } else {
                //4
                if let errorMessage = error?.userInfo?["error"] as? String {
                    self.showErrorView(error!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my Person class:

```
class Person: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Person"
    }

    var name: String = ""
    var stores: [String : Store] = [:]

    init(name: String, stores: [String : Store]) {
    self.name = name
    self.stores = stores

    super.init()
}

}
```

My Store Class:

```
class Store: PFObject, PFSubclassing {


    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Store"
    }


    var name: String = ""
    var clothingSizes: [String: String] = [:]


    init(name: String, clothingSizes: [String: String]){
        self.name = name
        self.clothingSizes = clothingSizes
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: @luk2302 No, omitting the parentheses is perfectly fine.

Comment: @matt okay, wasn´t sure.

Comment: @PSU Exactly which line does the error happen on?

Comment: By the way, this code makes no sense: `if let errorMessage = error?.userInfo?["error"] as? String {self.showErrorView(error!)}` You are creating a variable `errorMessage` but not using it for anything. In Swift 2.0 you'll be slapped down for doing that.

Comment: @PSU What is the Store class? I would think that would have to be a PFObject subclass too, since it's a referenced property of Person. If it's not that seems like a likely caus

Comment: @Matt I added my store class if helpful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For both Parse subclasses, you need to make your inits convenience inits. Basically, what's going on is there is no implementation of init(), which you could do, by calling

```
override init() {

    super.init()    

}
```

Another option is to make your init a convenience init, and calling self.init()

```
convenience init(name: String, stores: [String : Store]) {

    self.init()
    self.name = name
    self.stores = stores

}
```